# Why does my grade table look like this?

Tags: exam

I'm writing an exam and I've got 2 sections: a 20 question multiple choice and an 8 question short answer.
[image: grade table]

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\begin{document}
\section{multiple choice}
\begin{questions}

\question[1] example question 
\begin{checkboxes}
\choice a
\choice b
\end{checkboxes}
\end{questions} 

\section{short answer} 
\begin{questions}
\question[2] sample question
\end{questions}

\newpage 
\multirowgradetable{2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable tex code resulting in your given screenshot...

Comment: @Mensch Thank you, done!

Comment: That code does not compile.  If I get it to compile, the table looks nothing like the table you've shown us.  We can't easily debug what we can't see.

Comment: @Teepeemm sorry, i forgot to end the checkboxes

Comment: please fix your question so that the code and output are from the same document and _say in words what ouput you want_

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong structure, starting and ending the environment `questions` twice.

This is the wrong result:[image: w]

```
%% WRONG code

\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\begin{document}

\section{multiple choice}
\begin{questions}   
    \question[22] example question 
    \begin{checkboxes}
    \choice a
    \choice b       
    \end{checkboxes}
    \question[21] example question 
    \begin{checkboxes}
    \choice a
    \choice b       
    \end{checkboxes}
\end{questions} % wrong<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\section{short answer} 
\begin{questions}    % wrong<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \question[20] sample question
        \question[19] sample question
        \question[18] sample question
        \question[17] sample question
        \question[16] sample question
        \question[15] sample question
        \question[14] sample question
        \question[13] sample question
        \question[12] sample question
        \question[11] sample question
        \question[10] sample question
        \question[9] sample question
        \question[8] sample question
        \question[7] sample question
        \question[6] sample question
        \question[5] sample question
        \question[4] sample question                    
        \question[3] sample question
        \question[2] sample question            
\end{questions}

\multirowgradetable{2}[questions]

\end{document}
```

This is the **right** result:

[image: r]

```
%%  RIGHT code

\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
    \section{multiple choice}   
    \question[22] example question 
    \begin{checkboxes}
    \choice a
    \choice b       
    \end{checkboxes}
    \question[21] example question 
    \begin{checkboxes}
        \choice a
        \choice b       
    \end{checkboxes}
%   \end{questions} % wrong<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\section{short answer} 
%   \begin{questions}   % wrong<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \question[20] sample question
        \question[19] sample question
        \question[18] sample question
        \question[17] sample question
        \question[16] sample question
        \question[15] sample question
        \question[14] sample question
        \question[13] sample question
        \question[12] sample question
        \question[11] sample question
        \question[10] sample question
        \question[9] sample question
        \question[8] sample question
        \question[7] sample question
        \question[6] sample question
        \question[5] sample question
        \question[4] sample question                    
        \question[3] sample question
        \question[2] sample question                
\end{questions}

\multirowgradetable{2}[questions]

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE** after follow-up question: There are 20 multiple choice questions and 8 short answer questions.

What you want are two grade tables, the first for questions 1-20 and the second for questions 21-28.

It is possible to define one or more “grading ranges”,  then to count the points in a range
and create grading tables  that cover only that range.

`\begingradingrange{myrange}` at the start of the range and

`\endgradingrange{myrange}` at the end of the range.

Then you can create a grading table that covers only the questions in a range
by using the command  `\partialgradetable{myrange}` or `\multirowpartialgradetable{2}{myrange}`.

The code defines a range `mcrange` to group the multiple choice questions ans `sarange` for the short answer questions.

[image: z]

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\begin{document}    

\begin{questions}
    \section{multiple choice}   
    \begingradingrange{mcrange} 
        \question[4] example question 
        \begin{checkboxes}
            \choice a
            \choice b       
        \end{checkboxes}
        \question[10] example question 
        \begin{checkboxes}
            \choice a
            \choice b       
        \end{checkboxes}    
        \question[7] example question 
        \begin{checkboxes}
            \choice a
            \choice b       
        \end{checkboxes}
        \question[7] example question 
        \begin{checkboxes}
            \choice a
            \choice b       
        \end{checkboxes}
        \question[5] example question 
        \begin{checkboxes}
            \choice a
            \choice b       
        \end{checkboxes}
        \question[2] example question 
        \begin{checkboxes}
            \choice a
            \choice b       
        \end{checkboxes}
        \question[2] example question 
        \begin{checkboxes}
            \choice a
            \choice b       
        \end{checkboxes}
        \question[2] example question 
        \begin{checkboxes}
            \choice a
            \choice b       
        \end{checkboxes}
        \question[1] example question 
        \begin{checkboxes}
            \choice a
            \choice b       
        \end{checkboxes}
        \question[1] example question 
        \begin{checkboxes}
            \choice a
            \choice b       
        \end{checkboxes}
        \question[1] example question 
        \begin{checkboxes}
            \choice a
            \choice b       
        \end{checkboxes}
        \question[1] example question 
        \begin{checkboxes}
            \choice a
            \choice b       
        \end{checkboxes}
        \question[1] example question 
        \begin{checkboxes}
            \choice a
            \choice b       
        \end{checkboxes}
        \question[1] example question 
        \begin{checkboxes}
            \choice a
            \choice b       
        \end{checkboxes}
        \question[1] example question 
        \begin{checkboxes}
            \choice a
            \choice b       
        \end{checkboxes}
        \question[1] example question 
        \begin{checkboxes}
            \choice a
            \choice b       
        \end{checkboxes}
        \question[1] example question 
        \begin{checkboxes}
            \choice a
            \choice b       
        \end{checkboxes}
        \question[1] example question 
        \begin{checkboxes}
            \choice a
            \choice b       
        \end{checkboxes}
        \question[1] example question 
        \begin{checkboxes}
            \choice a
            \choice b       
        \end{checkboxes}
        \question[1] example question 
        \begin{checkboxes}
            \choice a
            \choice b       
        \end{checkboxes}
    \endgradingrange{mcrange}

\section{short answer} 
    \begingradingrange{sarange}         
        \question[6] sample question
        \question[7] sample question
        \question[8] sample question
        \question[1] sample question
        \question[2] sample question
        \question[3] sample question
        \question[4] sample question
        \question[5] sample question        
    \endgradingrange{sarange}       
\end{questions}

\newpage

\multirowpartialgradetable{2}{mcrange}% two rows over the first range

\bigskip

\partialgradetable{sarange}[h] % one row horizontal over the second range

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for reverse engineering example code;-)

Comment: Thanks for this, but the reason I started and ended twice was because I wanted MC to go from 1-20 and short answer to start from 1 again. The number in the box represents the number of marks, not the question number.

Comment: @Brian Thank you for your feedback! Please see the updated answer. The question numbers can be changed 1-20 and 1-8, but then the grading tables will not work correctly.